# Insert Count Number for each time the row is seen and order by date using BigQuery SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

Say I have the following entries

```
| country | cases  |    date    |
|:-------:|:------:|:----------:|
|    US   |   100  | 2020-02-07 |
|    US   |   102  | 2020-02-08 |
|    UK   |   101  | 2020-02-12 |
|    UK   |   103  | 2020-02-13 |
```

I would like it to be like the following:

```
| country | cases |    date    | record_count_per_country |
|:-------:|:-----:|:----------:|:------------------------:|
|    US   |  100  | 2020-02-07 |             1            |
|    US   |  102  | 2020-02-08 |             2            |
|    UK   |  101  | 2020-02-12 |             1            |
|    UK   |  103  | 2020-02-13 |             2            |
```

Where we add a column, that is record number for the order of the records per country.
For the US the 1st record is for the 1st date, and the 2nd record is for the second date.

I am not quite sure how to do this in a SQL query.

### Update

For more information since the question was closed. I am looking at COVID-19 data and was hoping to generate the curves shown in the news. Where the number of cases is shown after a certain number was reached. I am plotting the data in Google Data Studio.

Comment: Can you reexplain the purpose of the record_count_per_country column? What is the calculation that it stores?

Comment: What's the database? I removed the inconsistent tags. Please add the engine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `PostgreSQL`, or `MySQL 8+`, you can use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html):

```
SELECT country, cases, date,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY country ORDER BY date) AS record_count_per_country
FROM data
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/34a2d/1)

Comment: `rank()` instead of `row_number()` could also be used

Comment: @Andronicus for OPs sample data that would be the same but if there were multiple values on the same date you would get a different result.